# VBA : Remove a link break from a html string and replace it with a space

Tags: vba, strip

```
        **Original String**                          **Result**
             CMP                                 CMP Rs.
             Rs.

             Mar Cap                             Mar Cap Rs.Cr.
             Rs.Cr.

             Debt                                Debt Rs.Cr.
             Rs.Cr.

             # Shares                            #Shares C.
             Cr.
```

> Strip works on a multiline string i.e **Strip(String, ".")** strips a **dot** on every line in a string but **Strip(String, "\n")** doesnt work. Is **linebreak** a **delimiter**?

Comment: There are different characters that can accomplish a linebreak, but if it's a standard one try `Replace(String, Chr(10), " ")`

Comment: @Vegard Its a html string, accomplished by a 'br' tag

Comment: @Vegard Your solution added a 'space', at the beginning of every second line in the string.

Comment: I guess it's a different linebreak character then. To find which it is, assuming you use the top string for example (from your original dataset, not the one pasted here), do `? ASC(Mid(String, 4))`. Then do the code in previous comment, but replace the 10 in `Chr(10)` with whatever number you got from `Asc`

Comment: @Vegard Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Strip(String, vbLf)
```

or

```
Strip(String, vbCrLf)
```

Documentation on these constants and more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/miscellaneous-constants).

Comment: could you share the actual data file? The invisible white space could be caused by various characters and it would be a quick fix with the actual string.

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming we are taking the string from the first line :

```
Dim Result As String
Dim Vhcv As IHTMLTableCell
Dim j As Long

    For j = 1 To Len(Vhcv.innerText)

    If Asc(Mid(Vhcv.innerText, j)) = 13 Then

       Result = Replace(Vhcv.innerText, vbCrLf, " ")

       Debug.Print Result

    End If

Next
```

> End Result :
>
> ```
>          CMP Rs.
>
>          Mar Cap Rs.Cr.
>
>          Debt Rs.Cr.
>
>          # Shares Cr.
> ```